# Player class not exported in the latest version of video.js error

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I'm trying to translate [this React example](https://videojs.com/guides/react/) provided by video.js to Typescript but I can't get pass the error below since Player is not exported in the latest version of video.js.

From the example code I get this error:

```
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //..
    const playerRef = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
       //Error: Type 'Player' is not assignable to type 'null'
       //..
    });
  }
```

When I try to add the type, like in a working [example(older version)](https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-with-react-typescript-8z22h?file=/src/video.tsx:452-500) I found, I get this error:

```
import videojs from 'video.js';

const playerRef = React.useRef<videojs.Player>();
Error: 'videojs' has no exported member named 'Player'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this import to add the Player type:

```
import Player from "video.js/dist/types/player";
```

and change:

```
const playerRef = React.useRef<videojs.Player>();
```

to

```
const playerRef = React.useRef<Player>();
```

Let me know if it works.